# gpg is just the binary name of GnuPG, let's synonymize them

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

There's [gnupg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnupg), which is the actual project name, and [gpg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpg) just being the binary.

Irrespective of all the confusion between GnuPG, GPG, PGP and OpenPGP and when to use which name (and tag), these two should be synonymized; I've never seen a question that only fits one of the two and can't really imagine one. Even their tag wikis are exactly the same.

Sadly the [tag synonym proposed on-site](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gnupg/synonyms) doesn't really receive a lot of attention; the tag is obviously a rather low-traffic one.

So please, make [gpg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpg) a synonym of [gnupg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnupg), which is the real name of the product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider it [done](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gnupg/synonyms).

Comment: Hum, [it seems there is no automatic merging of synonymized tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131506/should-tag-synonyms-be-automatically-retagged-to-the-master-tag). Especially as right now, a majority of [tag:gnupg] questions is not to be found using the tag (formerly having [tag:gpg]).

Comment: @Jens Erat: We don't want to merge tags automatically in case we want to remove the synonym. The old tag is still there in the DB but it will always appear as the new tag to viewers.